# Hibernate: Why am I getting an empty json?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have a simple entity class:

```
@Entity(name = "User")
@Table(name = "users")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private Integer age;
    private String email;
}
```

A repository:

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {

}
```

A service:

```
@Service
public class UserService {

    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    public UserService(UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    public Iterable<User> findAllUsers() {
        return userRepository.findAll();
    }

    public <U extends User> void saveUser(U user) {
        userRepository.save(user);
    }
}
```

A controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("api/v1/users")
public class UserController {

    private final UserService userService;

    public UserController(UserService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    @GetMapping
    public Iterable<User> getAllUsers() {
        return userService.findAllUsers();
    }
 
    @PostMapping
    public void addUser(@RequestBody User user) {
        userService.saveUser(user);
    }
}
```

And a yaml file:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    username: "root"
    password: "123123"
    url: "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydbtest"
    driverClassName: "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
  jpa:
    hibernate.ddl-auto: update
    generate-ddl: true
    show-sql: true
```

I use MYSQL Workbench, where I have a database with one table called users. Sending a get request and trying to get all the objects from the table, I get an empty json. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems ok to me . I think its your IDE issue, you have to enable  Lombok annotation processing in your IDE. You can follow this [link](https://www.baeldung.com/lombok-ide#:%7E:text=Annotation%20processing%20isn%27t%20enabled%20by%20default%2C%20though.&text=We%20need%20to%20go%20to,project%20classpath%20option%20is%20selected) to enable it.

Answer (score 0):

Could you add `@AllArgsConstructor` annotation to your entity. I think it might solve your issue. Since currently you only have `@NoArgsConstructor` and `@RequiredArgsConstructor` which comes bundled with `@Data`. And also you don't necessarily need the name paramenter in `@Entity`